# Json.Net deserialization results in null objects

Tags: c#, json

I am working on deserializing a json response and I am getting null values:

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "version": "4.2",
            "code": 0,
            "message": "Success"
        },
        "start": 0,
        "total": 12,
        "biographies": [{
            "text": "\"Radiohead\" are an English alternative rock band from Abingdon, Oxfordshire, formed in 1985. The band consists of Thom Yorke (vocals, guitars, piano), Jonny Greenwood (guitars, keyboards, other instruments), Ed O'Brien (guitars, backing vocals), Colin Greenwood (bass, synthesisers) and Phil Selway (drums, percussion).",
            "site": "wikipedia",
            "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiohead",
            "license": {
                "type": "cc-by-sa",
                "attribution": "n/a",
                "url": ""
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

This is the class I use to serialize the json above.

```
public class Response : IResponse
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public List<Biography> biographies { get; set; } 
}
```

The response contains more than one biography:

```
public class Biography
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string site { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public LicenseInfo license { get; set; }
}

public class LicenseInfo
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string attribution { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Why are all of the values returning null for the `Response` class?

In this case `T` is `Response`:

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
```

Comment: put your json here http://json2csharp.com/ and get your full class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to deserialize you need to create a class that contains the `response` property.

```
public class RootObject
{
     public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the `RootObject` class to deserialize.